# Problem referencing predefined variable in {{ if/elseif/else }} template syntax in Azure Pipelines YAML

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In the following edited and simplified snippet of Azure Pipelines YAML, I'm not able to get distributionGroupIds set to `<guid2>`.

As shown below, it returns `<guid1>`.
If I change 'merge' to 'whatever' if returns `<guid3>`

In both cases, the release notes show as:

```
[merge]
[refs/head/my-branch-name]
```

So, why doesn't the elseif evaluate to true and distributionGroupIds get set to `<guid2>`?

```
    - template: publish-appcenter.yml
      parameters: 
        ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge') }}:
          distributionGroupIds: '<guid1>'
        ${{ elseif eq(variables['system.pullRequest.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/my-branch-name') }}:
          distributionGroupIds: '<guid2>'
        ${{ else }}:
          distributionGroupIds: '<guid3>'

        releaseNotesText: |
          [$(Build.SourceBranchName)] #prints [merge]
          [$(system.pullRequest.sourceBranch)] #prints [refs/heads/my-branch-name]
```

Rereading my question it does have an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem?wprov=sfti1). Fundamentally my objective is to distribute specific PR source branch builds to specific distribution groups. The above approach isn’t working. How can I achieve my objective?

Comment: You're missing a colon after `${{ else }}`, but I'd be surprised if that's relevant.

Comment: @DanielMann good catch! Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

After more (a lot more!) trial and error I think I understand now that the ${{ if }} is evaluated at ‘compile time’.

And for whatever reason variables[‘Build.SourceBranchName’] is available at compile time *but variables[‘system.PullRequest.SourceBranch’] is not.*

Very few of the predefined variables seem to be defined and usable at compile time. The only one that gets me close to where I want to be is Build.SourceBranch which evaluates to something like refs/head/734/merge. Where 734 is the PR number. So, I can use:

```
${{ if contains(variables[‘Build.SourceBranch’], 734) }}
```

I’d prefer to use branch name but PR number is an acceptable proxy.